# SAPUI5 Variant key on Save strange behaviour

Tags: sapui5, variant

I am trying to implement a Variant management in SAPUI5 using Personalization service of sap.ushell.Container. I have written functions to Save, Manage(delete, rename) and select Variants from the drop down. However i see strange behavior when i select a variant in the method mentioned below.

```
onSelectVariant: function (oEvent) {
    var sSelectedVariantKey = oEvent.getParameter('key');
```

Assume i have existing variants 'A1', 'A2' and 'A3'.
When i SaveAs a new variant with new values (lets call it 'X1'), the new variant is created. Then i select another already existing variant from dropdown( A1 or A2 or A3), i see the corresponding values. Now i again select the newly created variant X1 but i don't see the new values.

When i debug the above mentioned method, i see that for all the existing variants, the `oEvent.getParameter('key')` returns the variant indexs like 0,1,2,3 etc. but for the newly created variant X1, it returns the value 'sv1579082806311' and hence it doens't find it in variantset

```
oPersonalizationVariantSet.getVariant(sVariantKey)
```

and then it doesn't show the new values.

If i run the program again, i see that previously created variant X1 now shows correct values as the method `oEvent.getParameter('key')` returns the index and not 'sv....'. but if i now create a new variant X2, the same issue happens with X2.

I am running the App on cloud WebIDE and not on the FIORI launchpad.

Can someone help me what may be going wrong while saving the variant ?

Thanks

Br
Nilesh Puranik

Comment: Add an answer with the solution that worked for me.
I had the exact same problem recently but for the "Save" button, I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61329675/sapui5-variant-key-on-save-issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue recently. I assume that this is a bug in the VariantManagement control. You could create an Issue in the openui5 github project.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and came to the conclusion its a bug in VM control.  It gives a new and long key to a newly saved variant.  In the oEvent parameter "key" of your onSelect function you will see this new key.

I soved the issue by adding a new property to my JSON object I bound for variants.
In Variant Save event:

```
tableModel.oData.tabVariants.push({key: VariantParam.key, 
                                  text: VariantParam.name, 
                                  newKey:this.oVariant.getVariantKey()})
```

Then in variant select event:

```
var selectedKey = oEvent.getParameter("key");
var variant = this.woTableSet.getVariant(selectedKey);
if(!variant){
  //In this case its a newly created variant with an internal key
  //This is a workaround for the key confusion in variants
  selectedKey = tableModel.oData.tabVariants.find(t => t.key === 
  selectedKey).newKey;
  variant = this.woTableSet.getVariant(selectedKey)
  if(!variant){return} //then I give up
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need replace the auto generated key by variant key:

```
const autoGeneratedKey = oEvent.getParameters().key;

this.oContainer.save().done(function (cb) {
    const oVM = that.getView().byId("vm");
    oVM.replaceKey(autoGeneratedKey, that.oVariant.getVariantKey());
    oVM.setInitialSelectionKey(that.oVariant.getVariantKey());
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).